# Adding printers though python

Tags: python, windows, printers

Just wanted to see if any one had a link to a resource or can give me a lead on installing printers/drivers remotely using python. I want to automate it so it installs local printers.

They are windows computers and i am on windows.

I would like to do this with out installing python on all the computers.

Comment: This might help you...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6326042/send-a-print-job-to-usb-printer-using-python

Comment: @user2239197: It might, but this question was about INSTALLING printers, while that was about ACTUALLY printing.

Comment: @Danger: It's probably going to be difficult to get a remote computer to do ANYTHING without having software installed on it that is designed to allow that thing to occur. That would be a SERIOUS security hole in the operating system. You might want to rethink your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try [`win32print`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print.html) module from the [`pywin32`](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32) package.

Specifically, [`win32print.AddPrinter`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print__AddPrinter_meth.html) and [`win32print.GetPrinterDriverDirectory`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32print__GetPrinterDriverDirectory_meth.html) look relevant.